# PHP session settings ignored on Apache production?

Tags: php, apache, session, centos, virtualhost

I'm having trouble with setting up PHP sessions for a project of ours and would like to ask for help. The goal was to prolong shopping cart data validity (stored in sessions) by increasing session lifetime.

**The issue is, no matter what I do, no matter the settings, the session file gets deleted after a few hours.**

I set it up in the virtual host definition like so:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ...
    php_value    memory_limit            128M
    php_value    upload_max_filesize     20M
    php_value    post_max_size           20M
    php_value    session.cookie_lifetime 2592000
    php_value    session.gc_maxlifetime  2592000
    php_value    session.save_path       "/data/hosting/myproject/sessions"
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Even moved the session storage to a dedicated directory to avoid any possible system upkeep clearing the sessions, without success.

**On a development enviroment (Wamp 3.0.6 64b) this works just fine** and as intended, not so much on the production server. Also, when I attempt to double-check the set up values using the PHP *ini_get()* function (http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-get.php), both development and production enviroments return the correct, required values.

The project is stored on a VPS on which we use these:

- PHP 5.5.38
- Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)
- CentOS Linux release 6.0 (Final)

A noteworthy observation – it's not just this project, the same setup fails when applied to another project as well.

Thanks in advance for any tip or idea that would help me solve this one, it would be much appreciated.

*Disclaimer*: Please do not comment on the solution itself, I am well aware of it not being optimal. It's an old project and it's simply not viable to rewrite the shopping cart data storing method.

Answer (score 0):

Well.. 
1) Verify that in code there isn't a ini_set that fiddles with the gc. Since that would override any setting you put in apache. 
2) Verify that there is no .htaccess doing the same thing as 1, since it would obviously also trash the settings.
3) Set the divisor/probability (might help)
4) Enforce set_cookie parameters as well, it might not be the server messing up but the clients that are getting default session cookie lifetimes and thus after 30 minutes would kill the cookie.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestions!